# Django, Python: Is there a simple way to convert PHP-style bracketed POST keys to multidimensional dict?

Tags: php, python, django, http, post

Specifically, I got a form that calls a Django service (written using Piston, but I don't think that's relevant), sending via POST something like this:

```
edu_type[3][name] => a
edu_type[3][spec] => b
edu_type[3][start_year] => c
edu_type[3][end_year] => d
edu_type[4][0][name] => Cisco
edu_type[4][0][spec] => CCNA
edu_type[4][0][start_year] => 2002
edu_type[4][0][end_year] => 2003
edu_type[4][1][name] => fiju
edu_type[4][1][spec] => briju
edu_type[4][1][start_year] => 1234
edu_type[4][1][end_year] => 5678
```

I would like to process this on the Python end to get something like this:

```
edu_type = {
    '3' : { 'name' : 'a', 'spec' : 'b', 'start_year' : 'c', end_year : 'd' },
    '4' : {
        '0' : { 'name' : 'Cisco', 'spec' : 'CCNA', 'start_year' : '2002', 'end_year' : '2003' },
        '1' : { 'name' : 'fiju', 'spec' : 'briju', 'start_year' : '1234', 'end_year' : '5678' },
    },
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want done.  The dict you want below acts like the one you have above.  What's the original data?  What do you mean by PHP-style bracketed POST keys?

Comment: HTTP POST (an PUT, but not relevant here) allows for sending name/value pairs as strings. The code above represents one such POST, with name strings on the left and values on the right.

PHP employs a trick which makes it simple to pass multi-dimensional arrays through POST requests: when a syntax like the one above is POSTed to a PHP script, it is immediately available in the $_POST superglobal as a native array. Because of that trick, the PHP programmers often don't think twice when sending data, which is the problem I got here -- I don't have the access to the calling code.

Comment: so do you receive the data as a string that looks like the code in your first code block?  or do you get a Python objects?

Comment: That's right, except it's not a single string, but key/value pairs received through POST request. To make things simpler, let's imagine that I have a dict that looks like the first example and want to turn it into the latter.

Comment: so for these key value pairs, "edu_type[3][end_year]" would be a key, and the value would be "d".  is that correct?

Comment: That's right; I apologize for using non-sensical values, I just use these for testing the transfer. In my app there should be an actual year (if it isn't it's considered an empty value), but that was irrelevant for this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a little parser in python to handle multidimensional dicts, you can find it at https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the solution I've been looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Dottedish does something like what you want. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dottedish. It doesn't really have a homepage but you can install it from pypi or download the source from github.

```
>>> import dottedish
>>> dottedish.unflatten([('3.name', 'a'), ('3.spec', 'b')])
{'3': {'name': 'a', 'spec': 'b'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am riding off of the previous response by Atli about using PHP's `json_encode`...

A Python dict in its most basic form is syntactically identical to JSON.  You could easily perform an `eval()` on a JSON structure to create a Python dict:

```
>>> blob = """{
...     '3' : { 'name' : 'a', 'spec' : 'b', 'start_year' : 'c', 'end_year' : 'd' },
...     '4' : {
...         '0' : { 'name' : 'Cisco', 'spec' : 'CCNA', 'start_year' : '2002', 'end_year' : '2003' },
...         '1' : { 'name' : 'fiju', 'spec' : 'briju', 'start_year' : '1234', 'end_year' : '5678' },
...     },
... }"""
>>> edu_type = eval(blob)
>>> edu_type
{'3': {'end_year': 'd', 'start_year': 'c', 'name': 'a', 'spec': 'b'}, '4': {'1': {'end_year': '5678', 'start_year': '1234', 'name': 'fiju', 'spec': 'briju'}, '0': {'end_year': '2003', 'start_year': '2002', 'name': 'Cisco', 'spec': 'CCNA'}}}
```

Now, is this the best way?  Probably not.  But it works and doesn't resort to regular expressions, which might technically be better but is definitely not a quicker option considering the time spent debugging and troubleshooting your pattern matching.

JSON is a good format to use for interstitial data transfer.

Python also has a `json` module as part of the Standard Library. While that is more picky about the output you're parsing, it is more certainly the better way to go about it (albeit with more work involved).

Answer (score 0):

okay, so this is ghetto as hell, but here goes:

let's say your input is a list of tuples.  say: input = [('edu_type[3][end_year]', 'd'), ...]

```
from collections import defaultdict
from re import compile

def defdict():
    return defaultdict(defdict)
edu_type = defdict()

inputs = [(x.replace('[', '["').replace(']', '"]'), y) for x, y in input]
for input in inputs:
    exec = '%s = "%s"' % input
```

Note that you should only use this if you trust the source of your input, as it is nowhere near safe.