# Passing Id to be used in controller via datatables ajax property

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, laravel-9

Im trying to get products variants using the product's id in the controller and displaying them using datatables server side processing as follows

```
      $("#productVariants").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: ["pageLength", "copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/shop/product/variants/",
        type: "GET",
        'data': {
            id: $("#productVariants").attr("rel"),
        },
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "description", name: "description" },
        { data: "cost", name: "cost" },
        { data: "status", name: "status" },
        { data: "id",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return (
                    '<div class="dropdown dropdown-action">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle"'+ 
                   'data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">'+
                   '<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>' +
                    '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">' +
                    '<a href="/shop/product/variants/' +
                    data +
                    '/edit"' +
                    'class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tooltip"' +
                    'data-placement="top" title="Edit">' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-pen"' +
                    'aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>' +
                    '<a rel="' +
                    data +
                    '" rel1="delete" href="javascript:"' +
                    'class="dropdown-item deleteProductVariant"' +
                    'data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">' +
                   '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>' +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
                );
            },
            name: "Action",
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
            printable: false
        }
    ],
    stateSave: true,
    bDestroy: true
});
```

I do have a route configured as follows

```
      Route::get('/variants/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'variants']);
```

In the controller, the function gets the id from the route as follows

```
      if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = $data = ProductVariant::join('statuses','product_variants.status_id',
      'statuses.id')->join('variant_types','product_variants.variant_type_id',
      'variant_types.id')->join('variant_categories','variant_types.cat_id',
      'variant_categories.id')->select('product_variants.id As id',
      'variant_types.name As name','product_variants.cost As cost',
      'variant_categories.name As category', 'statuses.name As status')
      ->where(['product_variants.p_id'=>$id])->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()->make(true);
    }
```

When I run it I get the following error in the console

```
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/product/variants/?draw=1&columns%
      5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=category&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%
      5D=category&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%
      5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue
      %5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1
      %5D%5Bdata%5D=name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=name&columns
      %5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable
      %5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1
      %5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata
      %5D=cost&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=cost&columns%5B2%5D%
      5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&
      columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%
      5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=
      status&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=status&columns%5B3%5D%
      5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&
      columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5
      Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&
      columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=Action&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable
      %5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%
      5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D
      %5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%
      5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&
     search%5Bregex%5D=false&id=742&_=1677158506437 404 (Not Found)
```

from my understanding, a new URL is being formed which is not found yet I expected the supplied URL to be used and the id passed just like is done in laravel routing.
How can I get to pass the id correctly and achieve the desired output?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem? A 404 error when calling the route might indicate that it does not exist

Comment: @NicoHaase I've indicated what I've done both in the JavaScript section, I have also said that I'm having a challenge passing the id to the route and subsequently to the controller. I have also offered my code for the controller side and the route just in case the issue is from there

Comment: Can you share the route definition that should match the given URL? `/variants/{id}` will obviously not match the URL that you've shared, as the ID parameter is missing

Comment: @NicoHaase to be honest, I have no idea how that URL is coming about and what I am asking for is how I can pass the id to the url. something like ```url: "/shop/product/variants/". $id,``` in my attempt, I have tried using data ```'data': { id: $("#productVariants").attr("rel"), },``` but from a close observation of the error, that makes the request a search and actially passes the id but not in a format that the route can capture

Comment: You should just set up a route for `/variants/` here, because that is the URL _path_ datatables makes the request to. All the parameters are, as can be clearly seen from your 404-ing example URL, put into the query string.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051550/server-side-data-tables-send-post-data-as-json) post mostly related to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, here is how I solved the problem.
I changed the route method to post removing the id variable from the route
I then changed the datatable code as follows

```
        $("#productVariants").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: ["pageLength", "copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        url: "/shop/product/variants/",
        type: "POST",
        'data': {
            id: $("#productVariants").attr("rel"),
        },
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "category", name: "category" },
        { data: "name", name: "name" },
        { data: "cost", name: "cost" },
        { data: "quantity", name: "quantity" },
        { data: "status", name: "status" },
        { data: "id",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return (
                    '<div class="dropdown dropdown-action">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>' +
                    '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">' +
                    '<a href="/shop/product/variants/' +
                    data +
                    '/edit"' +
                    'class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tooltip"' +
                    'data-placement="top" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pen"' +
                    'aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>' +
                    '<a rel="' +
                    data +
                    '" rel1="delete" href="javascript:"' +
                    'class="dropdown-item deleteProductVariant"' +
                    'data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>' +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
                );
            },
            name: "Action",
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
            printable: false
        }
    ],
    stateSave: true,
    bDestroy: true
});
```

Note that the only significant change is the change of method to post